# How do I install the Epson L220 printer driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, 64-bit, epson

I have bought an Epson L220 printer and would like to install the drivers onto my HP Laptop.

How do I get and install it on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (amd64 architecture)?

Comment: go to "printers" options, it finds printer, it searches and finds the drivers,  click forward

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please remember to mark it as the correct answer by clicking on the grey tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 8):

You need to install the drivers for the printer. This can be found on the Epson website.

Please go to:

1. [Epson Linux Printer Search](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX) or [Epson Linux Driver Support](https://epson.com/Support/wa00821).
2. Search for the `Epson L220` printer.

[image: Preview of searching for printer]

3. Click on the download link.

[image: Preview of all the files available at the time of writing]

4. Click on the accept link at the bottom of the page to say you agree to the terms.

[image: Preview of the agreement]

5. Click on the download button for your distro

- You will need the files that end with `amd64.deb`
  [image: Notice that it has _amd64.deb at the end, click on the download link]

6. Make sure you do this for all the files available in **step 3** above.
7. Install the `.deb` package files with your favourite package manager, e. g. [GDebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gdebi/) or Software Center (Ubuntu 16.04 or later only) or on the command-line:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i /path/to/pacakge.deb ...
   sudo apt install -f
   ```

As a side note, the best way to find if a printer is compatible is to search [OpenPrinting.org](http://www.openprinting.org/). I found the [Epson L220](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-L220_Series) printer there, and saw that it was compatible. I then searched for the recommended driver on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=epson-201401w) which pointed me to the [Epson Linux Driver](https://epson.com/Support/wa00821) website.

Comment: Epson Linux Driver link will show , Page not found .

Comment: https://epson.com/Support/wa00821 this is the link for epson linux driver support... the one on the answer is broken

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I've updated the link reference in the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Connect to internet, then add the printer in System Settings -> Printers.

The driver should be downloaded automatically.

If it does not, post a comment. I will tell you how to install it manually.

Comment: Can not instal Epson L220 all-in-one printer driver autometically . So please tell me how to install it , because I have the same problem with my printer.

Comment: You can always ask a new question where explain what the problem is.

Comment: I have been posted a new question a few minutes earlier on this topic describing all my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The steps to get this working on ubuntu are simple

- Download `epson-inkjet-printer-201401w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.x86_64` file.
- Extract it.
- Now `cd` into `opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201401w/ppds/Epson/`.
- Extract  your driver `.ppd` file.
- Now, search for `Printers` in your start menu.
- `Add` driver via `ppd`.

Thats it.